# Plot 'envelope' of graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a graph which looks very grassy. 
What I want is the following (see picture). I have a grassy graphy (blue line), but I want the envelope which clearly shows the peaks of the graph (red line - this line is drawn in paint). A group of peaks may added to 1 group of peak. I have tried the following in matlab, without success:
- smooth;
- basic tool of curve fitting;
- Hilbert transform;
- polyfit; 
- Toolbox Ezyfit.

[image]

Any suggestions how to deal with this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried spline in the basic curve fitting tool of Matlab, but I see too many peaks. Also tried spline as you suggested, but it either shows too many peaks or I lose  too much information...

Comment: why Hilbert transform did not work? It should do great

Comment: In my opinion you can do that by writing a function so that let's say it finds top ten maximum values of 'y' then sort them based on their 'x' values and plots x,y including beginning and end of range. And the more maximum you take your envelop will be smoother as well. If you need more help let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the signal processing toolbox, I would suggest to use the **Butterworth lowpass filter**. There are many tutorials for this on youtube.
It is a two-step process, you create the desired filter and then you can apply it on your data. With the right parameters, it will allow you to keep only the high frequencies ("enveloppe"), and eliminate the low frequencies.

You can verify the license for this function with:

```
which Butter
```

Comment: big and small frequencies? You mean high and low right?